# update query with specific data

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables: `sales` and `productlist`. Let's say I have these ff value for its table

This is the ff value of `sales`

```
id | pcode | qty_sold |
1  |  123  |  20      | 
2  |  123  |  20      |
```

This is the ff value for `productlist`

```
id | pcode | pleft | 
6  |  123  |  20   |  
7  |  333  |  40   |
```

My problem is this: When I update 1 product from `productlist` it updates properly with the product I want to update, but other product data is turned to 0. The expected value when updating the `productlist` must be look like this:

```
id | pcode | pleft | 
6  |  123  |  60   |  
7  |  333  |  40   |
```

I have this code so far:

```
mysql_query("UPDATE productlist SET pleft=pleft+(SELECT SUM(qty_sold) ".
            "FROM sales WHERE sales.pcode=productlist.pcode)");
```

But it displays like this:

```
id | pcode | pleft | 
6  |  123  |  60   |  
7  |  333  |  0    |
```

Comment: This is not clear at all what you are trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 1):

i guess you missed `WHERE` clause in your `UPDATE` statement, like:

```
UPDATE productlist 
    SET pleft=pleft+(SELECT SUM(qty_sold) FROM sales WHERE sales.pcode=productlist.pcode)
WHERE productlist.pcode = "your_id";
```

Answer (score 1):

You are only using `WHERE` for your inner query.

You have to use `WHERE` for outer query for updating particular record.

```
UPDATE productlist 
SET pleft=pleft+(SELECT SUM(qty_sold) FROM sales WHERE sales.pcode=productlist.pcode)
WHERE productlist.pcode = "id";
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason you get '0' is, Your select returns '40' for first ID but no rows returned for second. so it is considered as null. Thats y you get '0' for second id. Try using l ifnull(select,0) function.

```
UPDATE productlist SET pleft=pleft+ifnull((SELECT SUM(qty_sold)
        FROM sales WHERE sales.pcode=productlist.pcode),0)
```